# how to write sql query to fetch urls of present date (TODAYS) from chrome db?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I want to monitor child activity while using the internet. my app is in java. I want URLs to be saved in a text file. can you give me a hint for this? how to store URLs from all open tabs in a Google Chrome (or other browsers like Mozilla Firefox)  into a file using java? 
The code I am currently using is as under. what it does is it stores last 20 URLs. it is not working in real-time. can you plz update SQL query that takes URLs of present date or anyone of you knows the database structure of chrome history file.

```
Class.forName ("org.sqlite.JDBC");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\UserData\\Default\\History");
statement = connection.createStatement ();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM urls ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20 ");
//SELECT * FROM urls WHERE id=last
//url >= CURDATE()-3
while (resultSet.next ()) 
{
    System.out.println ("URL [" + resultSet.getString ("url") + "]" + ", visit count [" + resultSet.getString "visit_count") + "]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT url,count(*) as url_cnt FROM urls GROUP BY url_cnt
```